# How to resolve if attributes of a repository are not working?

Tags: android, attributes, xml-namespaces

I am using map fragment with MaterialAnimatedSwitch in my Activity.
There is not Java code yet.

In XML, when I try to add attributes from MaterialAnimatedSwitch , first they don't show on typing the first few letters,
then when I simply write the attributes as shown in https://github.com/glomadrian/material-animated-switch
the app crashes.

I understand it has something to with conflict of the namespaces as

```
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
```

both are involved.

I've tried with different possibilities, such as defining both in the root layout, defining one in the root and one in the map fragment, and so on.

But the result is the same. The app crashes with log

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: 
Unable to start activity ComponentInfo
{com.example.dell.vehicledrivers/com.example.dell.vehicledrivers.MapsActivity}: 
android.view.InflateException: 
Binary XML file line #19: Binary XML file line #19: 
Error inflating class com.github.glomadrian.materialanimatedswitch.MaterialAnimatedSwitch
```

I understand I'm making a very basic mistake, but I'm not able to find any hint of it. How can it be reolved?

EDIT

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MapsActivity" >

<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    tools:context=".MapsActivity" />

<com.github.glomadrian.materialanimatedswitch.MaterialAnimatedSwitch
    android:id="@+id/driverSwitch"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="45dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="45dp"
    app:base_release_color="@android:color/darker_gray"
    app:base_press_color="@android:color/white"
    app:ball_release_color="@android:color/darker_gray"
    app:ball_press_color="@android:color/white"
    app:icon_release="@drawable/ic_location_off_black_24dp"
    app:icon_press="@drawable/ic_location_on_black_24dp"
    />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Why are you declaring the same namespace twice?

Comment: the 'map' one came when I added the MapActivity.
then the MaterialAnimatedSwitch  attributes were not working, so I added the 'app' one

Comment: @GabeSechan hey I have aded the layout xml. Can you point out any mistakes?
or provide a useful link? Thanks